# deny access to index.php but allow index.php?var=val

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wonder if I can deny accessing http://domain.tld/index.php and allow only http://domain.tld/index.php?var=val

Is this possible with a rewritecond and rewriterule? I cannot figure this out. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  The trick to use a condition to check the query string, using this in your docroot `.htaccess` file which allows you to forbid access to index.php unless the variable var is set:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase    /

RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING}   !\bvar=
RewriteRule    index.php         -        [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a rewrite rule? If it's a PHP script, you could detect the absence of the required parameters and just return an appropriate HTTP header to deny access.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, it should be a .htaccess since the index.php script is encoded and I cannot modify it.